# Are Pym particles known on other planets?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man

[Hank Pym](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_Pym#/search) discovered a type of unstable subatomic particle that he was able to put into one formula that reduced an object's size, and another formula that increased the object's size.

In Guardians of the Galaxy, there are examples of size alterations.  Gamora's metal sword is able to shrink into its handle and then extend back to full size.  Peter Quill's helmet similarly rests as a small ear piece until he desires it to expand in size to cover his head.  And Rocket has been known to change size.

**Are there specific examples of Pym particles being known to non-Earthers, or of Hank Pym sharing his knowledge with people from other planets?**

[image]